# What is the parachain validation function (PVF)?

Tags: polkadot, parachain

I would like to better understand what the parachain validation function is and how it is used throughout Polkadot.

In [The Polkadot Parachain Host Implementers' Guide](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/book/glossary.html), it says that the parachain validation function (PVF) is:

> The validation code that is run by validators on parachains or parathreads.

Answer (score 6):

Parachain Validation Function (PVF)

```rust
/// A struct that carries code of a parachain validation function and its hash.
///
/// Should be cheap to clone.
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Pvf {
    pub(crate) code: Arc<Vec<u8>>,
    pub(crate) code_hash: ValidationCodeHash,
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/c289aced8c7f124acd60d0764de35cec1047549f/node/core/pvf/src/pvf.rs#L22-L29

Remember that a parachain runtime is essentially a state-transition function.

The parachain validation function or PVF for short, is the current runtime Wasm for a parachain that is stored on the Relay chain.

One example of where the parachain validation function (PVF) is used is in the Relay chain module: [`paras`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/596088a273eff13fbefe6fa20a5fef6507b329cb/polkadot/runtime/parachains/src/paras/mod.rs#L21-L23). This module tracks the state of parachains as mentioned at the top of its file:

```
//! The most important responsibility of this module is to track which parachains
//! are active and what their current state is. The current state of a para consists of the current
//! head data and the current validation code (AKA Parachain Validation Function (PVF)).
```

The parachain validation function (PVF) code is hashed and stored in the [`paras`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/596088a273eff13fbefe6fa20a5fef6507b329cb/polkadot/runtime/parachains/src/paras/mod.rs#L708) module:

```rust
/// The validation code hash of every live para.
///
/// Corresponding code can be retrieved with [`CodeByHash`].
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn current_code_hash)]
pub(super) type CurrentCodeHash<T: Config> =
    StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, ParaId, ValidationCodeHash>;
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/596088a273eff13fbefe6fa20a5fef6507b329cb/polkadot/runtime/parachains/src/paras/mod.rs#L703-L709

When successfully upgrading a parachain, the parachain's validation code (or parachain validation function) would change and therefore the `CurrentCodeHash` storage would reflect that by having a different `ValidationCodeHash`.

Another example of where the parachain validation function (PVF) is used is in [candidate validation](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/book/node/utility/candidate-validation.html).

When the parachain produces a new block, it sends a "Proof of Validity" (PoV) block to the Relay chain. This PoV-block or PoV is a parachain block with witness data. You can read more on this [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/596088a273eff13fbefe6fa20a5fef6507b329cb/cumulus/docs/overview.md#block-building). The Relay chain uses this PoV block along with the parachain validation function (PVF) and does a series of checks ([one example](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/596088a273eff13fbefe6fa20a5fef6507b329cb/polkadot/node/core/candidate-validation/src/lib.rs#L840-L868)) including [executing the PVF (Wasm) against the PoV](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/596088a273eff13fbefe6fa20a5fef6507b329cb/polkadot/node/core/pvf/src/host.rs#L94-L119). This is what is considered as [candidate validation](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/book/node/utility/candidate-validation.html) - we are checking to see if this parachain block is a successful candidate to be a block for that parachain. Much of this logic can be found in the [Candidate Validation subsystem](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/polkadot/node/core/candidate-validation/src/lib.rs) as noted in the top of its file:

```rust
//! This handles incoming requests from other subsystems to validate candidates
//! according to a validation function. This delegates validation to an underlying
//! pool of processes used for execution of the Wasm.
```

If these checks come out successful then this PoV block is deemed a worthy candidate and is ready for [candidate backing](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/book/types/backing.html).